# How do I get python to detect a right brace, and put a space after that?

Tags: python-3.x

beginner python programmer here. For my homework, I need the computer to identify the right brace '}' in this one conjoined string and seperate all of them into individual components.

`(->{200}o^{90}->{200}o^{90}->{200}o^{90}!0->{200}o^{90})`

The text above is the string. This string is in a separate txt document and you make the computer read the txt using `file.readlines()`

Then comes the part where you have to separate this string.

`(->{200}, o^{90}, ->{200}, o^{90}, ->{200}, o^{90}, ->{200}, o^{90})`

So the computers detects

```
->{200} as index [0]

o^{90} as index [1]

->{200} as index [2]

and so on...
```

I've tried to use `.find('}')` method then follow it up with a space but it doesn't work. I can't think of any other way to separate them.

What else could I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
>>> s = '->{200}o^{90}->{200}o^{90}->{200}o^{90}!0->{200}o^{90}'
>>> v = [i+'}' for i in s.split('}')]
>>> v
['->{200}', 'o^{90}', '->{200}', 'o^{90}', '->{200}', 'o^{90}', '!0->{200}', 'o^{90}', '}']
```

Note that this adds an extra brace at end of array. Just remove that with

```
>>> v = v[0:-1]
```

**Edit:** Or make it even better with @MrFuppes suggestion to avoid post-formatting:

```
>>> v = [i+'}' for i in s.split('}') if i]
```

Comment: `[i+'}' for i in s.split('}') if i]` to avoid the work-around ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Another possible way is using a regex finder in your string.

```py
import re
your_string = '(->{200}, o^{90}, ->{200}, o^{90}, ->{200}, o^{90}, ->{200}, o^{90})'
# List of characters inside brackets

result_list = re.findall(r'{[0-9]+}', your_string)
print(result_list)
# result_list will look something like this based on your example
['{200}', '{90}', '{200}', '{90}', '{200}', '{90}', '{200}', '{90}']
```

You can change the part inside the single quotes **{[0-9]+}** depending on the kind of values you expect inside the brackets.
For example "(->{[0-9]+}|o\^{[0-9]+})" will return a list of both `->{XXX}` and `o^{YYY}`

> ['->{200}', 'o^{90}', '->{200}', 'o^{90}', '->{200}', 'o^{90}', '->{200}', 'o^{90}']

Keep in mind that `findall` function returns a list so you can work on each individual match however you like.

Answer (score 0):

You should use str.split('}') https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_split.asp

I would do it this way :

```
string = '(->{200}o^{90}->{200}o^{90}->{200}o^{90}!0->{200}o^{90})'
# remove the '(  )''
string = string[1:-1]
# split the string
split_string = string.split('}')
# put back the '}''
split_string = [s + '}' for s in split_string if s is not '']
print(split_string)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the text and grab each character to make your own string, plus a comma and space when you encounter a }.

```
text = "(->{200}o^{90}->{200}o^{90}->{200}o^{90}!0->{200}o^{90})"
my_string = ""

for character in text:
    my_string += character
    if character == "}": my_string += ", "
```

This can be achieved in one line by using the `join` method too.

```
text = "(->{200}o^{90}->{200}o^{90}->{200}o^{90}!0->{200}o^{90})"
my_string = "".join(c + (", " if c == "}" else "") for c in text)
```

Then you just need to remove the extra `", "`.