# How do I get the computer to seperate a conjoined string into seperate items on a list depending on what it detects?

Tags: python-3.x

This is a follow up from a question I asked yesterday which I got brilliant responses for but now I have more problems :P

([How do I get python to detect a right brace, and put a space after that?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58337827/how-do-i-get-python-to-detect-a-right-brace-and-put-a-space-after-that/58338091#58338091))

Say I have this string that's in a txt document which I make Python read

!0->{100}!1o^{72}->{30}o^{72}->{30}o^{72}->{30}o^{72}->{30}o^{72}->{30}

I want to seperate this conjoined string into individual components that can be indexed after detecting a certain symbol.

If it detects !0, it's considered as one index.

If it detects ->{100}, that is also considered as another part of the list.

It seperates all of them into different parts until the computer prints out:

```
!0, ->{100}, !1, o^{72}, ->{30}
```

From yesterdays code, I tried a plethora of things.

I tried this technique which separates anything with '}' perfectly but has a hard time separating !0

```
text = "(->{200}o^{90}->{200}o^{90}->{200}o^{90}!0->{200}!1o^{90})" #this is an example string
my_string = ""

for character in text:
    my_string += character
    if character == "}": 
        my_string+= "," #up until this point, Guimonte's code perfectly splits "}"
    elif character == "0": #here is where I tried to get it to detect !0. it splits that, but places ',' on all zeroes
        my_string+= ","


print(my_string)
```

The output:

```
(->{20,0,},o^{90,},->{20,0,},o^{90,},->{20,0,},o^{90,},!0,->{20,0,},!1o^{90,},)
```

I want the out put to insead be:

```
(->{200}, o^{90}, ->{200}, o^{90}, ->{200}, o^{90}, !0, ->{200}, !1, o^{90})
```

It seperates !0 but it also messes with the other symbols. 
I'm starting to approach a check mate scenario. Is there anyway I can get it to split !0 and !1 as well as the right brace?

Comment: using string concattenation is wasteful - strings are immutable and get destroyed/creted new every time you do add somthing to them. Why not use a list? why not use a regex approach? What is the resulting list of elements you want to get from your string? `["20,0,","90,","20,0","90,"]` ... you talk about "indexes" and "another part of a list" - to me it is unclear what those mean in respect to what your output should be. Please clarify. When you are at it, also clarify what those other characters mean: `->`  and `o^`  etc

Comment: Alright so if I try to explain the meaning behind -> and o^, I might inadvertently ask for the answer for my entire homework and I don't wanna do that. I want to figure this out bit by bit. If you need a gist, basically the computer reads ->{100} and/or o^{90} and does a certain thing. Currently I'm trying to get a conjoined string to read certain symbols individually. I adjusted the output for the original code so it's clear on what I need. I just need it to seperate into a list instead of being one mushy mess.